# Is the SML `o` operator only useful on single-argument functions?

Tags: sml, smlnj, ml

Is the `o` composition operator (eg. `val x = foo o bar`, where `foo` and `bar` are both functions), only usable on single-argument functions and/or functions with equal numbers of arguments? If not, what is the syntax for, say, composing `foo(x,y)` with `bar(x)`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As Michael already said, yes, SML only has single argument functions. I want to elaborate a bit, though.

The following function:

```
fun foo (x,y) = x + y
```

Has the type:

```
fn : int * int -> int
```

Which means that the first argument is a tuple of two ints. So you could do something like:

```
(sign o foo) (4,~5)
```

Which would give you the same as `sign (foo (4,~5))`.

Okay, but what about something like this?

```
fun bar x y = x + y
```

It has the type:

```
fn : int -> int -> int
```

Which means that bar actually takes just one integer, and returns a function. So you can't do this:

```
(sign o bar) 4 ~5
```

Because bar returns a function, and sign takes an integer. You can do this, though:

```
(sign o bar 4) ~5
```

Because `bar 4` is a function that adds 4 to a number.

Comment: If you defined a `uncurry` function to help facilitate your last "problem" with `sign o bar`, and possibly also a `flip` function that can flip "argument ordering" by flipping the pair `(x,y)` to `(y,x)`, etc.

Comment: Jesper: In this case, I'd probably define a $ operator and do `sign $ bar x y`.

Answer (score 7):

SML only has single argument functions; `foo(x,y)` is a function `foo` taking a single argument, the tuple `(x, y)`. As such, there is no special handling needed and `bar(x)` will need to return a tuple of the appropriate type to compose it with `foo`.

Answer (score 4):

I've seen some Standard ML code (notably the Poly/ML code Isabelle/Pure) which puts extra composition operators into the top-level environment which handle this kind of situation. E.g.:

```
fun (f oo g) x y = f (g x y)
fun (f ooo g) x y z = f (g x y z)
fun (f oooo g) x y z w = f (g x y z w)
```

Generally, such things should be used sparingly (four or more o's is getting a bit silly), but it is quite useful having at least `oo` around.